# subset columns with common values in long data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
Group 1 ID A    Value
Group 1 ID B    Value
Group 1 ID C    Value
Group 2 ID B    Value
Group 2 ID C    Value
Group 3 ID B    Value
…   …   …
```

I am trying to use dplyr to get the mean value for each of the same ID across groups (e.g. the mean of the value of ID B across group 1, group 2, and group 3). However, not every group has all of the IDs so I wanted to subset so that only means for IDs which are in all groups get computed. I know that I can `group_by(dataFrame, group) %>% filter subset %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(mean)` but I don't know what code to place in the filter subset.

Comment: Do you know the total number of unique ID's in the dataset?  This could be as simple as, e.g., `filter(n_distinct(id) == 3)` after you group by `group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(count  = n()) %>%
  filter(count != ngroups) %>% #...
```

So basically remove all the rows in the dataframe that correspond to an ID that doesn't appear in all groups, then perform the computation.

Comment: You could combine the filter and mutate steps